# Azure VM shared storage account permission

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, file-permissions, azure-storage-account

We have an azure VM (Virtual Machine) hosting a web app in IIS but that uses files on the VM's file system. We want to move the files to an Azure Storage Account (so that if the VM losses the data we have the files still). We can do this, but when we try and give the storage account permissions on the VM it says it cant do it. Anyone know how to give the storage account permissions to write and us the file system through IIS?

[image]

Comment: Are you mapping a storage account file service share to the VM?

Comment: I believe so yes, azure gave us a script to run on the VM that sets up the connection to the storage account

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the reason that you want to change the permission of the mount point. But when you follow the steps in [Quickstart: Create and manage Azure Files share with Windows virtual machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-quick-create-use-windows) and finish all the steps, the Azure File Share was mounted to the Windows VM, then you cannot change the permission. And the admin users have full control of the mount point, the users can write, read and modify the files in the mount point.

I think when you use the admin users to run the IIS, then it already has the permission to write and read in the mount point. So you needn't change the permission.

Comment: Ok thank you, It may be the IIS user is not the admin user

Comment: @Andrew Do you try it? And if it works for you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: No I have not tried it, we currently keep the directory on the vm as that at least works for now. We may look into this again but no time at the moment.

Comment: @Andrew Well, if you try and it works for you, please accept it as the answer.